# Using JavaMail to connect to IMAP getting "A1 NO LOGIN failed" exception

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, exchange-server

Following is the detail of the server I'm trying to connect

```
    mailbox_password = KexDa3P7hEtru                            
    mailbox_domain = mail.lenderlive.com    
    mailbox_host= corp.lcl  
    mailbox_username = SecondaryQC@lenderlive.com
    server_type = imap
    port = 143
```

I'm using the following java code to connect to exchange:

```
    String domain = "mail.lenderlive.com";
    String user= "SecondaryQC@lenderlive.com";
    String password= "KexDa3P7hEtru";
    String serverType = "imap";

    Store store = null;  
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
    session.setDebug(true);
    store = session.getStore(serverType);
    store.connect(domain, user, password);
```

Here is the server trace that I have been getting:

```
    2016-11-02 15:01:22,885 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:80-1) DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4ea
    2016-11-02 15:01:22,888 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:80-1) DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
    2016-11-02 15:01:22,899 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:80-1) DEBUG: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
    2016-11-02 15:01:22,899 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:80-1) DEBUG: disable AUTH=PLAIN
    2016-11-02 15:01:22,910 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:80-1) * OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.
    2016-11-02 15:01:22,913 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:80-1) A0 CAPABILITY
    2016-11-02 15:01:22,915 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:80-1) * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=NTLM AUTH=GSSAPI AUTH=PLAIN STARTTLS UIDPLUS CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
    2016-11-02 15:01:22,915 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:80-1) A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
    2016-11-02 15:01:22,915 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:80-1) IMAP DEBUG: AUTH: NTLM
    2016-11-02 15:01:22,915 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:80-1) IMAP DEBUG: AUTH: GSSAPI
    2016-11-02 15:01:22,916 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:80-1) IMAP DEBUG: AUTH: PLAIN
    2016-11-02 15:01:22,922 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:80-1) DEBUG: protocolConnect login, host=mail.lenderlive.com, user=SecondaryQC@lenderlive.com, password=<non-null>
    2016-11-02 15:01:22,925 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:80-1) A1 LOGIN SecondaryQC@lenderlive.com KeDa3P7hEtru
    2016-11-02 15:01:22,928 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:80-1) A1 NO LOGIN failed.
```

Can someone please help and explain what exactly I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. You're using a very old version of JavaMail, please [upgrade](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) if you can.
2. You might need to [enable SSL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#smtpssl).
3. You should [change Session.getDefaultInstance to Session.getInstance](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#getdefaultinstance).
4. I hope you didn't really publish your password above.  :-)