# Sometimes login sometimes not to Exchange by JavaMail

Tags: java, email, debugging, jakarta-mail

I have problem with randomly login failed. By one hour is happening 2-4 times, and similar time, for example: about 14:26, 14:48, 15:26, 15:49, etc.

I use JavaMail(ver. 1.5.6) to email processing. Mailbox is Microsoft Exchange.
Application run every 5 minute to connect to mailbox.

Pseudocode for email processing:

```
 estabilishConncetion()
 prepareMailbox()
 downloadEmails()
 moveEmailsToSOmething()
 closeConnection()
```

Code connection is like this:

```
 public void establishConnection() throws ConnectionException {
    logger.info("Establish connection... ");
    props = new Properties();

    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.ssl.enable", "true");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.port", 993);
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.timeout", 60000);
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.connectiontimeout",60000 );

    props.put("mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable", "true");
    props.put("mail.imaps.auth.ntlm.disable", "true");
    props.put("mail.imaps.auth.gssapi.disable", "true");        
    props.setProperty("mail.debug", "true"); // only for test

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new Authenticator(){
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(somename, somepassword);
        }
    });

    try {
        store = session.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect(EmailServerAddress, EmailAddress,Password);
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new ConnectionException(" Problem occured when try connect to host: " + ServerAddress + " on address: " +EmailAddress);
    }
    logger.info("Connected to mailbox.");
}
```

Logging when connected:

> DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "somehost", port 993, isSSL true]]
>
> * OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.]]
>
> A0 CAPABILITY]]
>
> * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=NTLM AUTH=GSSAPI AUTH=PLAIN
>   STARTTLS UIDPLUS CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+]]
>
> A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.]]
>
> DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=somehost,
>   user=someuser, password=]]
>
> DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism LOGIN not supported by server]] DEBUG IMAPS:
>   LOGIN command trace suppressed]] DEBUG IMAPS: LOGIN command result: A1
>   OK LOGIN completed.]]
>
> A2 CAPABILITY]]   * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=NTLM AUTH=GSSAPI
>   AUTH=PLAIN STARTTLS UIDPLUS CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+]]
>
> A2 OK CAPABILITY completed.]]
>
> DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: NTLM]]   Connected to mailbox.]]

Logging when not connected:

> DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "somehost", port 993, isSSL
>   true]]
>
> * OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.]]
>
> A0 CAPABILITY]]
>
> * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=NTLM AUTH=GSSAPI AUTH=PLAIN
>   STARTTLS UIDPLUS CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+]]
>
> A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.]]
>
> DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=somehost, user=someuser,
>   password=]]
>
> DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism LOGIN not supported by server]]   DEBUG
>   IMAPS: LOGIN command trace suppressed]]   DEBUG IMAPS: LOGIN command
>   result: A1 NO LOGIN failed.]] //trying to login one more time with
>   failure

I checked this and its ok in my code:
1.  [Using JavaMail to connect to IMAP getting "A1 NO LOGIN failed" exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40390511/using-javamail-to-connect-to-imap-getting-a1-no-login-failed-exception)
2. https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#Exchange-login
3. I have unit test realted with connection and they always passed

Any sollution, clues, how to better debug this? :)

Comment: First, make sure you don't have a firewall or anti-virus product that may be intercepting your communication with the server.  If that's not the problem, it's time to look at the server logs since it seems to be the server that's rejecting your login.  Possibly you'll get more information about the failure by setting the property `mail.debug.auth` to `true` to get all the details of the authentication exchange in the JavaMail debug output (but don't post that here).

Comment: Good, i didn't not know about this logging, i thougt that its only `mail.debug` to `true`. I try and I waiting for error occurence, thanks.

Comment: `mail.debug.auth` giving only plaint text password :( About settings on server, I think they are correct, because another application simillar to this application working without this strange behavioral(connect to ex change too, exchange are similar(about configuration))

Comment: If it's using plain text passwords both when it succeeds and when it fails, and it's using the same user name and password in both cases, then the problem is in your server.

Comment: @BillShannon thank you for your help. It turned out that I make silly mistake. In one case, connection with mailbox isn't close, after fix - working fine :)