# JavaMail with IMAP getting “A1 NO LOGIN failed” exception

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, exchange-server, imap

This question is related to the following question: [Using JavaMail to connect to IMAP getting "A1 NO LOGIN failed" exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40390511/using-javamail-to-connect-to-imap-getting-a1-no-login-failed-exception/46120676#46120676)

I stumbled upon above thread since I get the same problem using JavaMail 1.6.0. We are trying to connect to a Exchange mailbox with IMAP. Thunderbird connects perfectly and so I suppose this is cause by some other issue related to JavaMail.

@Bill Shannon: I have done all the things you have highlighted above, except for the fact that we are using STARTTLS since SSL support is disabled in the Exchange server (Thunderbird also uses STARTTLS and connects correctly).

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.6.0
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | DEBUG IMAP: enable STARTTLS
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | DEBUG IMAP: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | DEBUG IMAP: trying to connect to host "mail.diversepower.com", port 143, isSSL false
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | * OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | A0 CAPABILITY
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 LOGINDISABLED STARTTLS UIDPLUS CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | DEBUG IMAP: protocolConnect login, host=mail.abc.com, user=abc@def.com, password=<non-null>
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | A1 STARTTLS
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | A1 OK Begin TLS negotiation now.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | A2 CAPABILITY
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN UIDPLUS CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | A2 OK CAPABILITY completed.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | DEBUG IMAP: mechanism PLAIN disabled by property: mail.imap.auth.plain.disable
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | DEBUG IMAP: mechanism LOGIN not supported by server
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | DEBUG IMAP: mechanism NTLM not supported by server
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | DEBUG IMAP: mechanism XOAUTH2 disabled by property: mail.imap.auth.xoauth2.disable
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | DEBUG IMAP: LOGIN command trace suppressed
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | DEBUG IMAP: LOGIN command result: A3 NO LOGIN failed.
```

Comment: You can set the `mail.debug.auth` property to true to get the details of the authentication exchange (but don't post it here).  That might provide more information about what's going wrong.  Other than that, make sure you're really [using the correct user name (in the correct format) and the correct password](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#Exchange-login).

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct user name?  See @Bill Shannon's link for username format.

Answer (score 3):

@Bill Shannon: Thanks much for all your help. Really appreciate it.

Thanks everyone for your input. Finally we managed to figure out the problem. We had to enable PLAIN and the username has to be specified as only the first part of the email address (**abc for an address of abc@def.com**). I believe the Exchange Server in this case was Exchange Server 2013.

Hope this helps for anyone who stumbles upon this same issue.

Comment: Yes, for Exchange only the username without domain works for PLAIN AUTH.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the part of your log telling you, what's going on:

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN UIDPLUS CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | A2 OK CAPABILITY completed.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | DEBUG IMAP: mechanism PLAIN disabled by property: mail.imap.auth.plain.disable
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | DEBUG IMAP: mechanism LOGIN not supported by server
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | DEBUG IMAP: mechanism NTLM not supported by server
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/09/07 20:59:02 | DEBUG IMAP: mechanism XOAUTH2 disabled by property: mail.imap.auth.xoauth2.disable
```

The server tells you about the possible ways to do the authentication. The client goes through its own mechanisms and checks if the server supports it or if there is a reason not to use it:

- `PLAIN` is supported by both sides but the use is deactivated on your side, because of a JavaMail Session-property `mail.imap.auth.plain.disable` set to `true`
- `LOGIN` is not supported by the server
- `NTLM` is not supported by the server
- `XOAUTH2` is not supported by the server and the use is deactivated on your side, because of a JavaMail Session-property `mail.imap.auth.xoauth2.disable` set to `true`

Because there are no common authentication mechanisms, authentication fails.

The solution for you here is removing the setting `mail.imap.auth.plain.disable` (or setting it to `false`) in your session properties.

Comment: After STARTTLS, Login is enabled by the server (AUTH=LOGIN is not), as the `LOGINDISABLED` capability has been removed.

Comment: @Max The available authentication mechanisms reported by the server is debug-outputted in line three of the log-block I quoted in my answer: `DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN`. There is no mention of the authentication mechanism `LOGIN` as you proposed. If I overlooked it, please prove your claim by quoting the corresponding line from the original log.

Comment: `AUTH=LOGIN` and `LOGIN` are not the same thing.  You are correct that `AUTH=LOGIN`, the SASL mechanism, is disabled.  Basic `LOGIN` does not have to be enabled, it is enabled by default.  It can be disabled by `LOGINDISABLED`  (RFC 3501 §6.2.3.).  This is why JavaMail attempts to use it here:  `DEBUG IMAP: LOGIN command trace suppressed`.  It is not attempting AUTH=LOGIN here.

Comment: @Max There are RFCs and then there is real life ;-). I'd still go trying out PLAIN authentication. If that fails as well, you can rule my theory out and check username-formats and password. If the problem is there, you can "redeactivate" the use of ' PLAIN'  and check if ' LOGIN'  now works now.

Comment: Yes, and in real life LOGIN and AUTH=LOGIN are completely different, and LOGIN almost always works.   @Bill Shannon and the JavaMail FAQ specifically advise disabling AUTH=PLAIN because it is buggy in certain versions of Exchange.

Comment: @Max is right.  The failure is because the LOGIN command failed, not because no authentication mechanism could be found.  That said, it's worth enabling PLAIN, just in case it works on this version of Exchange.  But I think it's more likely that the problem is with the format of the user name or password.